# Embed tweet in Leaflet marker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, leaflet

I am trying to display an embedded tweet in the popup of a Leaflet marker. I am using tweetframe to load the tweet into an iframe:

```
  var marker1 = L.marker(
    [52.3687433,4.8912132],
    {
      icon: new L.Icon.Default()
    }).addTo(map);

  var popup1 = L.popup({
    maxWidth: '2650'
  });

  var html1 = $('<div id="html" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;"><iframe class="tweet" id=tweet_493851197649207296 border=0 frameborder=0 height=250 width=550 src=https://twitframe.com/show?url=https://twitter.com/gideontailleur/status/493851197649207296></iframe></div>')[0];

  popup1.setContent(html1);
  marker1.bindPopup(popup1);
```

See live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t0on4cqn/)

Unfortunately, this doesn't look very nice, and I would like to use an actually embedded tweet. However adding this code as per the example on Twitter as the marker content does not seem to work. One of problem is that I cannot escape the quotes in the html which gives errors. More problems might pop up when I solved that:

```
    var marker2 = L.marker(
    [52.36,4.89],
    {
      icon: new L.Icon.Default()
    }).addTo(map);

  var popup2 = L.popup({
    maxWidth: '2650'
  });

  var html2 = $("<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Hey <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/WindowsInsiders?src=hash">#WindowsInsiders</a>, we have released Build 15063.2 for Mobile to Fast ring - includes a single fix March 29, 2017</a></blockquote><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>")[0];

  popup2.setContent(html2);
  marker2.bindPopup(popup2);
```

See live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dvzuqmq0/5/).

Answer (score 0):

The code highlighting on JSFiddle indicated a problem in the `html2` variable jQuery function call, right at the end there is:

```
</script>
```

This will cause to prematurely end the Javascript block. You simply need to escape this:

```
<\/script>
```